# Accessing properties from Microsoft.AnalysisServices Class

Tags: c#, ssas

I have been trying to  access  properties of Measure Group  of SSAS   from  following link. I am bad at  coding .

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154309(v=sql.120).aspx

My Expected Output is

```
MeasureGroupName (String) ,  Source  (string)
```

I could able to put some code as below .. Please help me to complete this job .

```
Cube cube = database.Cubes.FindByName(cubeName);
MeasureGroup sampleMeasureGroup = cube.MeasureGroups[0];
var measures = sampleMeasureGroup.Source;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "Source" of a measure group? Are you looking for DSV table name? Can you give a example?

Comment: Hi @GregGalloway !   I am using Microsoft business intelligence suit to create OLAP cubes . It is completely   UI based application. Data from RDBMS is pushed to  Measure Group  using  queries on RDBMS(dsv) .  Dsv is source of Measure Group .Microsoft provided  libraries and classes   to  implement the same objective  using Code.   Code has  more flexibility in interacting OLAP cubes .  I want to know programatically , which Dsv is tied with Measure Group , so that I can keep consolidated information in table.

Comment: But do you want to spit out the DSV name or the name of the table in the DSV?

Comment: @GregGalloway   I require only dsv Name and  Measure Group.                                                                   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the DSV name, it's the same for every measure group in a cube. So this code will get it:

```
        Cube cube = database.Cubes.FindByName(cubeName);
        string sDSV = cube.DataSourceView.Name;
```

To get the table name:

```
        Cube cube = database.Cubes.FindByName(cubeName);
        MeasureGroup sampleMeasureGroup = cube.MeasureGroups[0];
        DataItem di = sampleMeasureGroup.Measures[0].Source;

        if (di == null) return null;
        ColumnBinding cb = di.Source as ColumnBinding;
        RowBinding rb = di.Source as RowBinding;
        string sTableID = (cb != null ? cb.TableID : (rb != null ? rb.TableID : null));
        if (sTableID == null) return null;

        if (cube.DataSourceView.Schema.Tables[sTableID] != null)
        {
            if (cube.DataSourceView.Schema.Tables[sTableID].ExtendedProperties.ContainsKey("FriendlyName"))
            {
                return cube.DataSourceView.Schema.Tables[sTableID].ExtendedProperties["FriendlyName"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return cube.DataSourceView.Schema.Tables[sTableID].TableName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return sTableID;
        }
```

If you ever need to list the DSV table names for measure groups, then you might try this BIDS Helper [report](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/ColumnUsageReports/).

Or BIDS Helper is an open source project so you can see how it navigates measures and DSV tables [here](https://github.com/BIDeveloperExtensions/bideveloperextensions/blob/bidshelper-vsix/SSAS/UnusedColumnsPlugin.cs).

Comment: Then how to get  Named query that is used to  create measure Group. Basically , I am trying to push this information into tables . Later I can develop SSRS reports by querying on tables.

Comment: Edited my answer to include code for getting table name. It's a bit more complex.

Comment: Hi @VenkatSuryaSunilmodekurthy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.